# Set session using jquery - ajax, php not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hi I tried to set session using PHP but it is not working, I have no idea why.

Here is that code: 
PHP file for checking the login information with the database...

```js
 $query = "INSERT INTO login (name,`password`) VALUES ('$emailLog', '$passLog')";
                    $response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
                    if ($response) {
                        echo ('sent');
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['email'] == $row["email"];

                        header("refresh: 2", 'url= index.php');
                    } else {
                        echo mysqli_error($dbc);
                    }
```

PHP file (index.php) :

```js
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

.
.
some html code and then checking the session (which is always empty)
. 
.

```js
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    echo "logout";
} else {
    echo "login";
}
?>
```

That was my PHP code where I tried to set session, but after many times I decided to try setting session with jquery, and here is my code for that:

```js
if(data.indexOf('sent') > -1){
                         $("#alertLog").addClass('alert-success');
                         $("#alertLog").html('Logged in successfully');
                                 
                     $("#alertLog").slideDown(500).delay(1000).slideUp(500);
                         $('#emailLog').val("");
                         $('#passLog').val("");
                         $.session.set("email", 'emailSign');
                         location.replace("index.php");
}
```

When I try to login, it show me that I logged in successfully and set the value of the field to null (""), but it crash $.session.set('email', 'emailSign')...and some these error message:

--  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
    at Object.success

Any help either with PHP setting session or JQuery.

Comment: what is the framework you are using for php and you cant able to handle session in javascript

Comment: I;m not using any framework for php

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem...it was so stupid mistake...
in my PHP file I wrote: $_SESSION["email"] == $row["email"];
instead of  $_SESSION["email"] = $row["email"];

I put two equal sign...that was the mistake

Answer (score 0):

Session is server-side, JQuery is client-side.
JQuery generally knows absolutely nothing about sessions, if your are not using some plugin or whatever.